# Python OpenCv how do I detect when a video finishes playing?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am using Python 3.5 and Opencv for an interactive video. However I can't figure out how to detect when my video finishes playing. Any ideas how I can detect when the video ends?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: maybe checking the number of frames and the current frame number? also, it should give you empty images if it ended

Comment: How does your current cod elook like?

Answer (score 8):

When ret is False, it means that the video is in the last frame.

Here is my code.You can try it.

```
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("huge.mp4")
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This code appears to open and then instantly close the window but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

check [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) out. You can use the identifier `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` to get the Number of frames in the video file.

Comment: Thank you, so I tried to do that but then it says that `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` is not defined: `NameError: name 'CV2_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES' is not defined`. Do you maybe know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

## with OpenCV 3

cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT

## with OpenCV 2.4

cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).