# Run TensorFlow Object Detection API on video

Tags: python, object-detection

I am trying to run the TensorFlow Object Detection API. It works when I use it on my webcam with that line :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

But when I try to do it on a video with that line :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('kev.mp4')
```

I end up having that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leahj\Documents\models-master\research\object_detection\object_detection_tutorial_cam.py", line 147, in <module>
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  File "C:\Users\leahj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\leahj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1104, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\leahj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Both the video and the code are in this folder:

> C:\Users\leahj\Documents\models-master\research\object_detection

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('kev.mp4')
```

opencv can't read frames. because of this, variable "cap" is None. You can try checking if you can print any frames. Its about cv2.VideoCapture function i think.

Comment: When you look at the [documentation] (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), in the part Playing Video from file, there are the following lines though; 'cap =cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')' What do you think about it? What should I use instead of VideoCapture?

Comment: i tried to read a video file too after i write answer to you and i have the same problem. these two link may help us. -https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/26/opencv-resolving-nonetype-errors/   -https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8471

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the stream is opened properly. You can try it by using the below line.

cap.isOpened()

If above method returns true, it means, there is no problem reading the file. Then, you need to set which frame you want to read using below line.

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,frameNumber)

Then, you can read that particular frame as follows:

success,image = cap.read()

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when trying to run "Detect Objects Using Your Webcam" tutorial. But I guessed it caused by the lastframe +1 of the video. (something like last frame of video and when cv2 fetch next, it's gonna be out of video, a null frame for example.)
I tried and this was true.

```
# cut out the last frame to avoid error type.
if not ret:
   break
```

How to know the when video finish, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788247/python-opencv-how-do-i-detect-when-a-video-finishes-playing)

Put it where? something like this:

```
        # running
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        # cut out the last frame to avoid error type.
        if not ret:
            break
        # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)
        # write to output
        out.write(image_np)
        # Display output
        cv2.imshow('object detection', image_np)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, hope this helps anyone:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path_test)
    with od_graph.as_default():
        config = tf.ConfigProto()
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        with tf.Session(config=config, graph=od_graph) as sess:
            read_success = True
            while read_success:
                read_success, image_np = cap.read()
                image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
                # More code here... #
                if not read_success:
                   break
                (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
                        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
                        feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue and i solved it by typing the absolute location

from this;

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('kev.mp4')
```

to this;

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/*username*/*some directories*/kev.mp4')
```

that worked for me.